# how to get (the web page) of details specific location in the google maps API in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

i have an URL of the specific Location,, 
 in this URL show web page from google maps API this page have images of location, phone number ,website And more (please check the attachment ).. 
i need show it in the specific event like (onclickListener) ..

***the URL : https://www.google.com/maps?cid=14393067712956738491

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.b1:
       // First Location
        break;
    case R.id.b2:
       // second Location 
        break;
}   
}
```

[screen shot of web page from googleMaps API,, that i need put it in my App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhJPK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you anchor tag in you coding like this:

`TextView textView;
String cid = "14393067712956738491";
String link= "<a href=\"https://www.google.com/maps?cid=\"\ +cid +"\">Location Click</a>"
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(link));`

You can use this snippet in your code. Hope this will fullfil your requirements.

Comment: I need to get All branches from the google Maps API not only one location I dont have all url of All branches , i want to keep updates with new locations ..

Comment: Can you explain a little bit i.e. what is All branches and if you are getting url then what you want to do? & Want to updates current location to whom?